# Convert Mac Address and IP Address to byte araay of specific size

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte, ip-address, mac-address

I'm Trying to convert a mac address to a byte array of size 5 and an IP address to a size of 4. Now i know how to retrieve the values with this code:

```
'This returns a byte array of size 16
Dim ipArray As Byte() = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(Function(a As IPAddress) Not a.IsIPv6LinkLocal AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6Multicast AndAlso Not a.IsIPv6SiteLocal).First().GetAddressBytes

'This returns a byte array of size 6
Dim macArray As Byte() = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces(0).GetPhysicalAddress.GetAddressBytes
```

This doesn't give me the result i want and couldn't find a good solution to work with. For the IP i created a workaround i find dirty:

```
Dim ip As String = "192.168.0.10"
Dim _ip() As String = ip.Split(CChar("."))
Object.IpAddress = New Byte() {Byte.Parse(_ip(0)), Byte.Parse(_ip(1)), Byte.Parse(_ip(2)), Byte.Parse(_ip(3))}
```

Comment: You are likely fetching a 128 bit IPV6 address - hence the 16 bytes.

Comment: Ah thanks for the IP stuf this was indeed the problem... the answer of Vasya works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```vb
Dim ipArray As Byte() = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()).AddressList.Where(Function(a As IPAddress) a.AddressFamily =2).First().GetAddressBytes
```

Comment: Thanks, this works like a charm! Like Alex K. already said i got a IPv6 adres back hence the 16 bytes. However this still doesn't fix my MAC address problem?

Comment: EDIT: It's late time to quit it was exactly the same problem. Getting the right NIC MAC resulted in the right array size :-)

Comment: @Gforse: glad I was able to point you in the right direction!